# Java XPath question

Tags: java, xpath

I wrote some codes to parse the html using xpath and Java. The html file is something like:

```
    <div class="field_row">
    <label for="names">Names *</label>
    <input id="address.A" type="text" maxlength="15" size="32" value="12345" name="address.work">
    <span class="additional_info"> Information 1 </span>
    </div>
    <div class="field_row">
    <label for="names">Names *</label>
    <input id="address.B" type="text" maxlength="15" size="32" value="12345" name="address.work">
    <span class="additional_info"> Information 2 </span>
    </div>
```

And Java codes:

```
    public static final Element INFOFIELD= Element.findXPath(".//*[@class='additional_info'");
```

will let me get 'Information 1'; however, I need to retrieve 'Information 2'. Therefore, I use:

```
    public static final Element INFOFIELD= Element.findXPath(".//*[@class='additional_info' and @id='address.B']");
```

But got errors. Could you give me some hint please? Thanks. A.

Comment: Your first xpath works fine for me. Cant you retrieve the text 'Information 2' ? Also your markup has syntax errors where the <input> tags do not have a closed </input> tag

Answer (score 0):

You can create an XPath based on your input field (address.B), and then specify you want to access one of its sibling nodes and thus retrieve its data...

XPath:

```
//input[@id='address.B']/following-sibling::span[@class='additional_info']
```

as you can see after we find the input node with the id attribute 'address.b', we specify 'following-sibling'. This indicates that we want to select one of the siblings after the current node('address.B's input field). Then we specify which node that is followed by the attribute details: span[@class='additional_info']

some working code implementing the above XPath:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='address.B']/following-sibling::span[@class='additional_info']"));
System.out.println(element.getText());
```

will print 'Information 2'

You can use XPath axes in other related ways to access other nodes in the DOM (parents, children, siblings,etc).

http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_axes.asp

```
An axis defines a node-set relative to the current node.
```